# Solving a joint distibution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Y$ and $Z$ be discrete random variables and $W$ and $X$ be continuous.

Both $Y$ and $Z$ take values in {$0, 1$}.

Let $$p(w|X = x, Y = y, Z = z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{\left(-\frac{(w-z)^2}{2}\right)}$$

$$p(x|Y = y, Z = z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$

$p(Y = 0|Z = 0) = 0.1$

$p(Y = 1|Z = 0) = 0.9$

$p(Y = 0|Z = 1) = 0.3$

$p(Y = 1|Z = 1) = 0.7$

$p(Z = 0) = 0.2$

$p(Z = 1) = 0.8$

**Find:**$$\space p(Y = 1)$$

How would I start to solve this?
I recognize that the joint distributions are normal distributions, but not sure what to do with this information.

Comment: I am not sure if your formulas are rendering correctly on my computer.  Did you mean to write $p(w|X=x,Y=y,Z=z) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp( - (w-z)^2/2)$ and  $p(x|Y=y,Z=z) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp( - x^2/2)$ ?

Comment: Sorry about that. Reformatted question properly. But yes that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:
$$P(Y=1) = P(Y=1 \mathrm{\ and\ } Z=1) +  P(Y=1 \mathrm{\ and\ } Z=0)$$
$$P(Y=1 \mathrm{\ and\ } Z=0)= P(Y=1 | Z=0)\cdot P(Z=0)$$